# view the code/functions of a DLL file

Tags: function, dll

I need to view the code of a DLL file . I HAVE GONE THROUGH other posts where many tools like .net reflector, dotpeek , dependency walker  were suggested .Also I tried using visual studio.

However , most of them support only .net module and my dll is not supported. None of the posts solved my problem.I am unable to view the code inside DLL. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot see the source code of a compiled library. To see at least the published symbols and some more information, try Dependency Walker:

http://www.dependencywalker.com/